# Is anything special planned for the 10 years anniversary of Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, 10th-anniversary

It would be nice.

---

The oldest post of Stack Overflow is from [July 31st 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/):

[image: Stack Overflow question #1]

Comment: [This is the ___oldest___ post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1). It's deleted, though.

Comment: Just nitpicking a bit ;-)

Comment: I've heard rumours of SO running a top secret underground lab (very Resident Evil style - hopefully without the apocalyptic happenings) where they're bio-engineering real live unicorns to give away to every member of the site... (keep it hush hush though - I wouldn't want to ruin the surprise...)

Comment: @JonClements *you* get a unicorn, and *you* get a unicorn, and *you* get a unicorn...

Comment: Oh I see... @MarcGravell is your developer alias for when you're not hosting your chat show and giving away cars... okay Oprah - your secret's safe with me... *taps nose*...

Comment: @JonClements I cannot confirm or deny that - but I can observe that "Marc" and "Oprah" have never been seen in the same room together. Read from that what you will.

Comment: Also "Marc" claims to be living in a place straight out of Harry Potter.

Comment: So... nothing happened :|

Comment: i mean, plenty happened.

Comment: a number of questions were asked, a number of questions were answered, a number of questions were deleted, users came and went, etc etc

Comment: @KevinB: OK, and what's so special about it?

Comment: It's still here.

Comment: One or more podcast episodes would be in order. That [Joel Spolsky](https://twitter.com/spolsky) is actually on (no more lame excuses). And [Jeff Atwood](https://twitter.com/codinghorror). And perhaps other oldtimers. And some outsiders, with their stories.

Comment: Related [New swag for Stack Overflow's 10th birthday: wear-ables or desk-ables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314941/312043)